# Find option jQuery not working (I am using it wrong)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I have a tab that I want to slide up/down with jQuery. I have a working example build in Backbone.js but I can't seem to get it working without the backbone.js framework.

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/abayob/Lfndn8d6/)

It is a lot of code, so the details are in the JSfiddle. I have a short version here:

```
<ol class="sortable row list_item_area"><li pageid="1012" data-ordering="0">
    <div class="panel margin-10 panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading heading-sm padding-5-important main-handle">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <a class="btn _options-more" data-id="1012" title="Toon/verberg opties"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
            </div>
        <div class="panel-body no-padding" data-id="1009" style="display: none;">
            <form data-id="1009">
                <CONTENT here>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery scripts I have now:

```
$("._options-more").click(function(event){
    var clicked = $(event.currentTarget);
    
    if(clicked.attr('data-id'))
    {
        console.log(clicked.attr('data-id'));
        id=clicked.attr('data-id');
        $(this).find('.panel-body[data-id="'+ id +'"]').show();
        $(this).parent().find('.panel-body[data-id="'+ id +'"]').slideDown();
        clicked.find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
        clicked.removeClass('_options-more').addClass('_options-less');
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    });

$("._options-less").click(function(event){
        var clicked = $(event.currentTarget);

        if(clicked.attr('data-id'))
        {
            id=clicked.attr('data-id');
            $(this).find('._options-more[data-id="'+ id +'"]').show();
            $(this).parent().find('.panel-body[data-id="'+ id +'"]').slideUp();
            $(this).find('._more-options-container[data-id="'+ id +'"]').hide();
            clicked.find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
            clicked.removeClass('_options-less').addClass('_options-more');
        }

        event.preventDefault();
});
```

There are two mayor problems here:

1. The panel-body is not found by the selector and thus the css is not changed. Result: The panel-body stays hidden.
2. The "fa-chevron-down" seems to be found and changes to "fa-chevron-up", but the second script wont change it back?

Maybe I just need to start from scratch, but I would like to learn from this by finding out whats wrong. So every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a click callback, `this` will refer to the clicked element, in your case, the `<a>`

You can use `.closest('.panel')` to get the `.panel` element and then find the `.panel-body`:

```
$(this).closest('.panel').find('.more-options-container[data-id="' + id + '"]').show();
```

---

Regarding the `_options-less`, you need to use the `on` and not directly the `click` because there is no `_options-less` element when you set the `click` listener:

```
$(".panel").on('click', '._options-less', function (event) {
```

It will create a `click` listener for all `._options-less` existing now and in the future.

Documentation for `on` : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Nitpicky I know, but could you wrap `this` as code as well in your first sentence? Took me a min to understand what you meant

Comment: AWESOME. Thank you for your explanation. It's very clear and solves all my problems. :D